# Code compiles, but no console output

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks, gnu

My C++ code compiles and runs, but no output is printed to the console.  I think it has something to do with the string variables, but im not sure. Im a total noob, any help would be appreciated. I am using codeblocks with GNU GCC Compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string botlong, botshort, secondline;
    botlong = "bottles of beer on the wall,";
    botshort = "bottles of beer";
    secondline = "Take one down and pass it around,";
    for(int bottles = 99; bottles<=0; bottles--)
    {
        cout<<bottles <<botlong <<bottles <<botshort;
        for(int lostB = 98; lostB<=0; lostB--)
        {
            cout<<secondline<<lostB<<botlong;
        }
    }
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Did you try to add ``endl`` in order to see some results ?

Comment: Hmm. Tried adding a new line to your strings? like doing ' << endl '. Depending on your environment, strings without newline might have strange effects ...

Comment: @alifirat is right, you should `flush` the stream (or any stream for that matter) before the program ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It must be `>=` instead of `<=`, otherwise your loops are not entered:

```
for(int bottles = 99; bottles >= 0; --bottles)
{
  cout << bottles << botlong << bottles << botshort;
  for(int lostB = 98; lostB >= 0; --lostB)
  {
    cout << secondline << lostB << botlong;
  }
}
```

Comment: That was it. I appreciate the help. I guess with the way I had it, the expression (bottles <= 0) was never true, so it never entered the loop.  Thanks a bunch for helping me understand this!

Answer (score 0):

I think your condition in `for` loop doesn't hold on start. You have a typo, correct `bottles<=0` to `bottles>=0` and same with next `for` loop.

Comment: That was it, thanks! You and the above response helped me out a lot!